# Sinch Verification API resending same code

Tags: sinch, android-sinch-api, sinch-verification

My development team are using the JavaScript Sinch Verification method for verifying Mobile numbers.

The iOS app calls the server to request a Sinch Verification code to be sent via SMS.

On the initial request for a verification code, a code is successfully delivered. When I request via the iOS app for the code to be resent, my expectation is that a new code is generated and sent to the mobile number.

Developers in India have shown their mobile phone with a different verification codes being delivered following 2 concurrent requests.

I am in Australia calling the same service, and receive the same verification code for the 2 concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

so this is how it works.

if you request the code again without entering the wrong or right code for a short time period the same code is sent out. Why is that you may ask. The reason is to reduce a race condition in delivery of sms so the "wrong"/old  code is delivered after you made you second request. If you verify the code you received. and then make a new request the code will be different.

Comment: Thanks for providing that understanding. I have been able to successfully retrieve a new code after waiting some time.